# Relative Paths in Xcode scheme

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, you can "share" schemes so that they can be transferred via version control. One of the things you can do in a scheme is to specify an application to run when you run the scheme. This application is stored in the xcscheme file as an absolute path.

Is there anyway to get a relative path in the xcscheme? When I try, Xcode crashes on startup. It also crashes if I try using a bash variable in the path.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope. Not possible as far as I know.

Comment: Amazingly this bug still crashes even the Xcode 9 Beta

Answer (score 1):

When you export the scheme (using the settings icon at the bottom of the "manage schemes" dialog box,) it is exported in what looks like a non-absolute path way. 
Which might achieve what you asked for.
If not, what is the problem or goal that needs to be solved?

Comment: Unfortunately that still requires manual configuration. The problem is specified in the first paragraph of my question.